# I cannot get the "Read More" button to work!

Tags: wp-admin

First, some background...I am just starting with Wordpress, and am working on switching the website for my church (www.bvchurch.com) over to Wordpress (temporarily at www.bvchurch.com/wordpress).  We have a blog page which the pastor uses to post periodic updates.  He sends them to me, and I've been posting them. Not sure this matters, but when I post them, I go into the wp-admin site, I "Add New" post, and paste the content into the page, which ends up taking multiple blocks.  Anyway, the blog page contains 4 blog entries, which each have a "Read More" button.  I click the button, and it takes me to a separate page with just that entry, but it never expands the blog entry!  (see below)

[image]

I've looked around online, but a lot of the discussions mention editing the php files or similar modifications.  Unfortunately, I can't find anyway to modify the page, or even change in to the code view (see attached image)
[image]

Comment: Hi Paul! It would be helpful to shorten up the preamble and extraneous details. Instead, it would help to provide some code references. The details you provide above aren't enough to debug the issue, I'm afraid.

Comment: Sorry, I do tend to ramble, but the reason I provided the details I did (and not code) is precisely BECAUSE I couldn't view the code.  Right above the second picture I posted, I mentioned that I was having trouble finding the area to view/modify the code for the blog page.

Comment: Gotcha. This is WordPress.com or something similar? If so, you cannot edit the codebase at all.

Comment: Nah, I'm using the Wordpress functionality on GoDaddy (our current webhost).  I'm still poking around, but it is maddening trying to find out how to modify certain things.  Anyway, with that said, I think I've found what I need (had to go to Appearance --> Theme Editor), but it has literally been 20 years since I've done anything significant with PHP, so it should be interesting...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "code view", but the actual theme code is found under Settings > Theme Editor. I would not recommend using that if you are not an experienced coder.

The single post should open in the single.php or singular.php file, where the content file corresponding to the post type is pulled in from the template-parts directory. The content.php file will be used by default for regular posts. It should have a conditional statement to determine whether to use the_excerpt or the_content.

```
if( is_singular() ) {
the_content();
} else {
the_excerpt();
}
```

I am currently working on several themes for churches for use with my own [Church Options](https://wordpress.org/plugins/church-options/) plugin, feel free to contact me if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks!  I found it (actually under Appearance --> Theme Editor).  Now I just need to figure out what's going on with the various PHP pages...

Comment: Ok, so I've not edited any of the theme files, but this is what I did:  I didn't want the blog on the home page, so I set the home page as static, and set the blog page as a blank page I had created.  This is the behavior I've noticed:

Navigate to blog page (http://bvchurch.com/wordpress/pastors-blog/)   --> Click on "Read More" --> Goes to http://bvchurch.com/wordpress/pastors-blog/YYYY/MM/DD/  --> Click on "Read More"  --> Goes to http://bvchurch.com/wordpress/pastors-blog/YYYY/MM/DD/

So, basically, I'm in a loop.  It never displays the full content of the post

Comment: FYI - Found the section you were referring to in the content.php:

`code`
  <article class="entry-content">
    <?php
    if ( ( is_home() || is_archive() ) && get_theme_mod( 'content_view', 'excerpt' ) == 'excerpt' ) {

      the_excerpt();

    } else {

      the_content();

      wp_link_pages( array(
        'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'fell' ),
        'after' => '</div>',
        'link_before' => '<span class="page-number">',
        'link_after' => '</span>',
      ) );
    
    }

    ?>
`code`

Comment: `get_theme_mod( 'content_view', 'excerpt' ) == 'excerpt'`suggests there is a setting in the customizer to choose the_excerpt() or the_content(). get_theme_mod() is how customizer settings are pulled.